# What does () mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm testing immediately invoked function in javascript. I found when running below code in Chrome, it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

```
function foo(){
    console.log(1);
}();
```

I think the parser break this code to two parts: a function declaration and `();`. But what would happen if I add a `1` between `()`, turns out it won't throw any error.

So I suppose `(1);` is a valid expression, but what does it means?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: `(1)` has the same meaning as `(1+0)` or `var x =2, y=1; (x-y)` -- that is, the braces are part of a maths/arithmetic expression. For this very same reason, if you look at the answers below they merely surround the function with `()` to make it work - it changes a function **declaration** into a function **expression**

Comment: Note: in any programming language, expressions are things that are NOT functions but return a value. In a function expression, forcing the function to be created inside an expression makes it return a value - a pointer to the function defined. Therefore you can use that value - in this case call it.

Comment: The answer is that `()`, when not used as a function call is simply a grouping operator. For it to be valid, it needs at least one valid expression inside it. That's why you get the error when it's empty. In your case `1` is a valid expression. You can have multiple expressions as well, if they're separated by commas. `(1, "foo", some.func("xyz"))`. Or you can use them to override operator precedence. `(2 + 3) * 4` is different from `2 + 3 * 4`

Comment: ...so you're right. The parser sees it as two independent statements instead of an immediately invoked function.

Comment: Thanks slebetman & squint. Your answers are what I want. BTW, how could I close this question and set your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression**:

```
(function foo(){
    console.log(1);
})();  // call the function here
```

Explanation:

Suppose you create a function:

```
function foo(){
        console.log(1);
}
```

Now to call this function we do:

```
foo()
```

Now if you saw we just gave the function name and called it. Now we can call it in the same line like:

```
(function foo(){
            console.log(1);
})();
```

Here is an [article you can read](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He's asking  what `(1)` on its own means.

Comment: Actually, what the OP has is not an immediately-invoked function expression because they are missing some parens to make it an expression.  The OP's code causes a syntax error.

Comment: @squint: i have updated the answer, and i think know it exactly answers OP's question. Sorry for missing this. If anything is still missing let me know.

Comment: Sorry, but your update isn't correct (or is confusing). It's a function declaration in both cases. The OP correctly determined this in the question. So what he sees is that there's a function declaration with a separate `()` after it in one case, and a function declaration with a separate `(1)` statement after it in the other. So he's asking why `()` alone is invalid and `(1)` alone is valid, and what the parens actually mean in JS.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(){
   //code goes here
 })();
```

Is what you want.

Putting the one there simply passes 1 as a parameter into the immediate function. If you did a console.dir(arguments) inside of the function when passing in 1 it would print out the number you passed in.

```
(function(){
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.dir(args); // prints [1][
 })(1);
```

In other words you create the function and then call it immediately. Using ().

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He's asking  what `(1)` on its own means.